# Expresso Store no_results

Tags: expresso-store, search, no-results

I am using expresso store:search tag in a page and I am submitting a price range (min/max) to the tag as follows:

```
{exp:store:search channel="products" search:price:min="{post:min_price}" search:price:max="{post:max_price}" category="{segment_category_ids}" paginate='bottom' dynamic_parameters="orderby|limit|sort"}
```

There is a lot going on in this I know, but it does work - to a point. When I do a search for a combination that doesn't exist (say there is nothing in that price range) I get a blank page because there are no entries associated.

My question is, does store:search have a no_results tag pair? And if so, how is it implemented? I looked through the documentation and in here, but have found nothing to direct me and it seems like it should be part of a search tag by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Store search tag is basically a wrapper for the channel entries tag pair with the ability to search Store specific functionality.

So you would want to do something along the lines of:

```
{exp:store:search channel="products" search:price:min="{post:min_price}" search:price:max="{post:max_price}"}

{!-- this will show if their are entries --}
 {title} - {price} - {your_custom_fields} 

 {if no_results}
  There are no items for this search.
 {/if}

{/exp:store:search}
```

So any tags you would use in the channels entries tag pair should be available in your search tag pair.